# blocking an if statement error message from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am trying to design a batch program that scans the D:\ on my computer for a CD album and then opens a program to play it. I don't want to use Autoplay because want to design my own custom program for the purpose. I am using an IF statement and a GOTO statement that loops back to the IF statement after a delay. Here is what I have:

```
:rescan
if exist D:\Track01.cda start (my soon-to-be music playing program)
timeout 2 /NOBREAK
goto rescan
```

The problem is that if there is no CD in the drive, the IF statement causes a seprate error message window to pop up.

Is there any way to block this message?

Comment: How about making use of the `else` clause?

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to use this? I also forgot to mension that I have the nircmd program and the error message title is "cmd.exe - No Disk" I tried `if exist D:\Track01.cda (start _my program_) else nircmd win close title "cmd.exe - No Disk"` but the message pops up at `D:\Track01.cda` and stops any further reading of the command line until you hit OK. @CristiFati

Comment: This error message doesn't come up on my machine (Windows 7 Pro). What are you using?

Comment: the popup appears with my Windows 7 Enterprise (English version) but not with my Windows 7 Enterprise (German version). Sometimes, Microsoft is hard to understand... (maybe this behaviour can be configured?)

Comment: I am using Windows Vista Home Premium SP2 English version with an AMD 64 Dual Processor. Also, I wouldn't doubt that this popup is a config of the OS. I just want a work-around to block it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to block this message as it is occurring outside of the control of your batch file. However I checked the existence of the drive before entering the loop and this seemed to work for my tests.

```
IF EXIST D:\ GOTO rescan
echo Drive does not exist
goto end

:rescan
if exist D:\Track01.cda echo start (my soon-to-be music playing program)
timeout 6 /NOBREAK
goto rescan

:end
```

Hope it helps you out.

Comment: I see what you were trying to get at but it still didn't work for me. The error message still came up.

Answer (score 0):

use another command:

```
dir D:\track01.cda 1>nul 2>&1 && start (your program)
```

If there is no disk, `dir` returns `The device is not ready.` and an `%errorlevel%`of `1`. If there is a disk, but no audio-disk (no "track01.cda"), `dir` returns "File not found" and an `%errorlevel%`of `1`

(All output of `dir` is redirected to `nul` to keep the screen clear - change that, if you want that output).

`&&` works as "if previous command was successful then"  ("if %errorlevel% is not 0")

Comment: Sorry, but this solution didn't work either. It just moved on as if the line were nothing, nomatter if the CD was in or not.

Comment: remove `1>nul 2>&1` to see any messages. What does it say? Are you sure, there _ is_ a `track01.cda`? Works for me with a pure Audio CD, but failed with a "mixed content CD" (no `trackXX.cda`). You might want to add `|| echo no Audio CD found` to the end of the line.

Comment: I don't know if it was caused by this command, but the driver for my CD drive became corrupted and uninstalled itself. I can't seem to fix it. I am so glad that I was doing this on my old computer!

Comment: I would be _very_ suprised, if `dir` were able to corrupt any driver. And I also don't think it was your music playing program (given, it's not a "soon-to-be" anymore)

Comment: Whatever it was, something got messed up.